# What will be the Node.js equivalent of this php json_encode ?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am looking for the Node.js of the following PHP Script:

```
$SMA_APICall = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=".$symbolValue."&interval=15min&time_period=10&series_type=close&apikey=R3MGTYHWHQ2LXMRS";
          $SMAresponse = file_get_contents($SMA_APICall);
          $jsonSMA = json_encode( $SMAresponse);
```

Here, I am trying to make a call to an API. The API call returns a json object. 
I want to repeat the same thing using Node js

Comment: Give `JSON.parse` a try.

Comment: How do I make call to the API. I used this : var jsonFile = "link to api" .  This gives me jsonFile  variable holding a string of the link. Instead I want to get the data from the link.

Comment: errr .... you are already getting json from the http call, so no need to encode it (in php above).  What you probably want is json_decode (in  php) which is typically a `JSON.parse` in js. Also, dont post publicly your api keys for services you subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to do is making a request to an API and get the JSON data.
Here's how you can do it with native Node.js module `https`

```
 const https = require('https');

 https.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=${symbolValue}&interval=15min&time_period=10&series_type=close&apikey=R3MGTYHWHQ2LXMRS`, (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // JSON Data Here
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

There're several other ways you can do this with other simpler packages. I highly recommend `axios` because it's cleaner and easier.

The full examples please refer to [this article](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `request` library: https://github.com/request/request

```
var request = require('request');
var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=" + symbolValue + "&interval=15min&time_period=10&series_type=close&apikey=R3MGTYHWHQ2LXMRS";
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonSMA = JSON.parse(body);
    // Continue code here
  }
});
```

Comment: It says cannot find module 'request'. What to do about this?

Comment: You need to install this module. Run `npm install --save request` on your command line. `--save` will add it as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

Comment: So now, all the data I am getting is being stored in jsonSMA. The issue which I am facing right now is , how do I access the data in jsonSMA globally.  I have to make such API Calls to many different APIs. So how to i make a global variable jsonSMA. I tried creating var jsonSMA outside of the request call. It doesn't work/

Comment: Node.js is asynchronous unlike PHP. This has many advantages for web applications but it takes some getting used to. See https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/. If you need to make a number of API requests, I would recommend looking into the `async` module - https://github.com/caolan/async.